# Show users which have permission about specific database

Tags: mysql, database, permissions

Is there a way to log in as root user of MySQL and show all users which have any permission about specified database?

Comment: Do you have the password for the `root` user account?

Comment: Is this a local personal use version of MYSQL? Or are you trying to access a MYSQL Server that someone else manages?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I have the password of root user and this is a local personal use version of MYSQL

Comment: Then try @KRONWALLED answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried that but I got `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table ' ... ' doesn't exist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
USE mysql;
SELECT user,host FROM db WHERE db='name';
SELECT user,host FROM tables_priv WHERE db='name';
SELECT user,host FROM columns_priv WHERE db='name';
SELECT user,host FROM procs_priv WHERE db='name';
```

First statement gets all users who have permissions on the database itself. The other 3 queries are for users who have only permissions on tables, columns or procedure level.

Sadly can't reference to another user who posted this. I learned it from there but can't find it anymore.

Comment: I tried first command but I got: `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table '...' doesn't exist`

Comment: You have to use the database mysql. This is an actual database that you should see in your environment.